# Reuse or renew an NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c, memory, nsmutablearray

If you have an array you're going to completely repopulate many times during an applications lifetime, would it be better memory-consumption/allocation-wise to...

1. alloc-init a new instance when I'm ready to repopulate, or
2. `removeAllObjects` on the existing instance to repopulate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As is typical with such a broad question, the answer is "it depends".

The better answer is, "don't worry about it". Seriously, this is called premature optimization. Unless you run into a real memory issue, either approach will result in negligible differences.